# ¿Cómo obtener todos los elementos con una etiqueta y asociarlos con otro elemento hermano usando minidom?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

Tengo un xml parecido a este

```
<root>
<header>
<ecode>0</ecode>
<edesc/>
</header>
<body>
<Prof>
<nom>nombre</nom>
<rut>rut</rut>
<urlAg>url</urlAg>
<fechTit>fecha</fechTit>
<uni>universidad</uni>
<EspeProf>
<Esp>
<nomEsp>especialidad 1</nomEsp>
</Esp>
</EspeProf>
<CMProf>
<CM>
<nomCM>centro medico</nomCM>
</CM>
</CMProf>
</Prof>
<Prof>
<nom>nombre</nom>
<rut>rut</rut>
<urlAg>url</urlAg>
<fechTit>fecha </fechTit>
<uni>universidad</uni>
<EspeProf>
<Esp>
<nomEsp>especialidad 1</nomEsp>
</Esp>
<Esp>
<nomEsp>especialidad 2</nomEsp>
</Esp>
</EspeProf>
<CMProf>
<CM>
<nomCM>centro medico</nomCM>
</CM>
</CMProf>
</Prof>
</root>
```

y necesito extraer solo la primera especialidad.

Lo intenté, pero por ejemplo si tengo 3 médicos y el médico número 2 tiene 2 especialidades, lo que sucede con mi código actual es lo siguiente:
imprime el primer médico con su especialidad la cual era solo 1 especialidad y el segundo también me lo imprime bien con la primera especialidad, el problema esta cuando se imprime el tercer médico ya que aparece la segunda especialidad del médico numero 2 la cual no le pertenece al médico 3.

Mi pregunta es cómo debería hacer para que el médico con 2 especialidades se vuelva a imprimir con su segunda especialidad. Adjunto el código de mi programa:

```
data = []
try:

    if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
        ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    url = '******'

    xml = urlopen(url)
    xml_string = xml.read()
    xml.close()
    xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml_string)
    nombre=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('nom')
    especialidad=xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('nomEsp').childNodes[0]
    for nom, esp in zip(nombre, especialidad): 
      nombremedico=nom.firstChild.nodeValue
      especialidadmedico=esp.firstChild.data
      print(nombremedico)
      print(especialidadmedico)
      data.append({"name":nombremedico,"info":especialidadmedico})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partiendo de tu mismo ejemplo formateado y corregido (faltaba cerrar la etiqueta `body`):

```
xml_string = '''
<root>
   <header>
      <ecode>0</ecode>
      <edesc />
   </header>
   <body>
      <Prof>
         <nom>Nombre1</nom>
         <rut>rut</rut>
         <urlAg>url</urlAg>
         <fechTit>fecha</fechTit>
         <uni>universidad</uni>
         <EspeProf>
            <Esp>
               <nomEsp>especialidad 1</nomEsp>
            </Esp>
            <Esp>
               <nomEsp>especialidad 2</nomEsp>
            </Esp>
         </EspeProf>
         <CMProf>
            <CM>
               <nomCM>centro medico</nomCM>
            </CM>
         </CMProf>
      </Prof>
      <Prof>
         <nom>Nombre2</nom>
         <rut>rut</rut>
         <urlAg>url</urlAg>
         <fechTit>fecha</fechTit>
         <uni>universidad</uni>
         <EspeProf>
            <Esp>
               <nomEsp>especialidad 3</nomEsp>
            </Esp>
            <Esp>
               <nomEsp>especialidad 4</nomEsp>
            </Esp>
         </EspeProf>
         <CMProf>
            <CM>
               <nomCM>centro medico</nomCM>
            </CM>
         </CMProf>
      </Prof>
   </body>
</root>
'''
```

Para facilitarte la tarea, es mucho más simple si iteras sobre los nodos `Prof`:

```
import  xml.dom.minidom as minidom


xmldoc = minidom.parseString(xml_string)
for prof in xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Prof'):
    nombre = prof.getElementsByTagName('nom')[0].firstChild.nodeValue
    for especialidad in prof.getElementsByTagName('nomEsp'):
        print(nombre,">", especialidad.firstChild.nodeValue)
```

No se si puedes o te has planteado usar [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.get) en vez de [`xml.dom.minidom`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#module-xml.dom.minidom), personalmente creo que es más "ameno". Puedes hacer simplemente:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
for prof in root.iter('Prof'):
    nombre = prof.find('nom').text
    for especialidad in prof.findall("./EspeProf/Esp/nomEsp"):
        print(nombre, ">" ,especialidad.text)
```

**Salida en ambos casos:**

> Nombre1 > especialidad 1
>   Nombre1 > especialidad 2
>   Nombre2 > especialidad 3
>   Nombre2 > especialidad 4

Estoy asumiendo que existe siempre al menos una etiqueta `<nom>`, de no ser así, es fácil solventarlo con un condicionale por ejemplo.

Comment: muchas gracias me sirvio justo para lo que necesitaba hice una modificacion y me sale de la siguiente manera
VARGAS RAMIREZ KATHERINE MARCELA -> PEDIATRIA Y OTRAS CONSUL INFAN
| VARGAS RAMIREZ KATHERINE MARCELA -> MEDICINA FAMILIAR INFANTIL

Comment: Rodrigo justo estaba editando tu pregunta cuando me percaté de que la pregunta del cuerpo no coincidía con la del título exactamente. He editado mi respuesta para obtener la salida que comentas en ambos casos, dado que creo que esa era tu intención realmente, creo que el título me despistó algo :). Un saludo.

Comment: muchisimas gracias por la ayuda ahora ya me quedo super claro :)